# How to whitelist the facebook app or to connect to Facebook representative?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

we are helping small business to create a page through apis.
We have tested through  test version of facebook app and test users.

Now we want to to test it with real users and production version of facebook app.
As they have mentioned in documentaion https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started#create-page

> You can only create a Page as a test user or if your app is
>   whitelisted. (You can apply through your Facebook representative.)

So question are

1. is there any procedure to whitelist the app ? or to connect to Facebook representative. Is there any link to do that ?
2. can adding "publish page" permission will solve the problem without connecting to Facebook representative or without whitelisting app .
3. or any other permission do we required .

Comment: I don’t think there is any info on where to find or contact such a representative. This is more of an “if you know, you know” thing - if your app / your business _was_ a large enough player, then you would have been told who to contact on such matters somewhere along the line already.